# Export MPMediaItem to server in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, http, mp3, aac, mpmediaitem

I would like to give users the ability to upload an audio file from their iPhone to a server which will host their media for them. I understand that I can use the MPMediaPickerController to let them pick a song, but I am wondering how to send this file to my server. I was thinking of using HTTP post and capping the filesize at ~25MB. If it was an image, I could just send it, but I am wondering how to do the same with a MPMediaItem.